# Android, Firebase - Displaying right activity for user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have two usertypes in my application. I am using Firebase realtime database to store username and usertype without using Firebase Authentication. My database:

```
User
 Unique ID
  username: John
  usertype: Teacher
```

My questions is how I can send the user to a activity based on the usertype. I thought i could do something like this:

```
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child("usertype").equals("Teacher") ){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

But this does not seem to work, as it always goes to the ThirdActivity. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is "database" instantiated?

Comment: This is how:         database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Comment: Please add the declaration of your `database` field.

Comment: try my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you need to use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("User").child(userId);

usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child("usertype").getValue(String.class).equals("Teacher") ){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

If you use authentication, to get the id, you need to use the foloowing lines of code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
```

If you don't use authentication, then you need to `store the uid in a variable`. When you generate that id is the moment in which you need store it. In this way you'll be able to to use it later.

Comment: How do I get the userID?

Comment: But as i mentioned in my question, I don't use Firebase Authentication

Comment: Okay, i have saved the uid in a variable and used sharedpreferences to use the uid in another activity. This seems to work

Comment: Yes, it's perfect. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

1. First, convert `DataSnapshot` object to `User` class object:

   `User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);`
2. Second, try to match data you want like below:

   ```
   if (user.getUserType.equals("UserName"))
   {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   } else {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```